# if list is empty in that case how can i avoid null pointer exception in java?

Tags: java, collections, nullpointerexception

```
public static void selectEMployee() {
   if (list1.isEmpty()) {
         System.out.println("The list is empty");
   }else {
         System.out.println("The list of employees are");
         for (Employee emp : list1) {
           System.out.println("Name::" + emp.getName() + "\t EmpId::"
                            + emp.getEmpid() + "\t Address::" + emp.getAddress()
                            + "\tphone::" + emp.getPhone());
         }       
    }
}
```

when the list is empty I want to display "The list is empty" but it throws exception?

Comment: Show exception in stacktrace.

Comment: try `if (list1 != null && list1.isEmpty()) {`

Comment: isEmpty() will not throw an exception when the list is empty, but you will get a NullPointerException of your list1-variable is not initialized (and is in fact, null). 
the most common implementation of the isempty()-method is the following:
public boolean isEmpty() {
   return size == 0;
}
taken from the ArrayList-implementation.

Comment: This should not compile: there's an extra closing brave before the. "else"

Comment: Perhaps he should be addressing why the list is null, rather than catching if it is null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try It Once

```
public static void selectEMployee() {

  if (list1!=null && !list1.isEmpty()) {
      System.out.println("The list of employees are");

      for (Employee emp : list1) {
           System.out.println("Name::" + emp.getName() + "\t EmpId::"
            + emp.getEmpid() + "\t Address::" + emp.getAddress()
            + "\tphone::" + emp.getPhone());
      }

  } else {
      System.out.println("The list is empty");
  }
}
```

Comment: not good; you'd still get a NullPointerException in a different place: in `for (Employee emp : list1) {`

Answer (score 11):

There's a difference between a `list` object that is empty and a variable of type `list` which hasn't yet been assigned as a reference to a `list`.

i.e. check `list1 == null`. Don't test for emptiness if it *is* `null` as you'll get a `NullPointerException`.

Putting it together, write `if (list1 == null || list1.isEmpty()){` instead. This is safe since Java evaluates `if` statements from left to right and stops once it has an unambiguous answer.

Comment: @OP: And it's probably worth looking at why `list1` is `null` when you were expecting an empty, but existing, list.

Answer (score 2):

Apply this little fix and it will work:

```
if (list1 == null || list1.isEmpty()) {
    System.out.println("The list is empty");
}
```

Comment: `||` will again throw NPE use `&&` . Simple & Clear   `if ((list!= null) && !list.isEmpty())`

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void selectEMployee() {
            if (list1.isEmpty() || list1==null) //changes made here{
               System.out.println("The list is empty");
            }// this is not allowed here
            } else {
 System.out.println("The list of employees are");
                for (Employee emp : list1) {
                    System.out.println("Name::" + emp.getName() + "\t EmpId::"
                            + emp.getEmpid() + "\t Address::" + emp.getAddress()
                            + "\tphone::" + emp.getPhone());
                }


        }
```

you are closing } for method before if else for loop closes

Comment: That would give a compile-time error, OP mentions getting a NPE (i.e. runtime), thus it was likely just a typing error.

Comment: @Bathsheba I am just telling the OP the errors he is making,I have commented the line

Comment: @javaBeginner; hey good spot, +1! (Ain't it time you changed your name?) But not the whole story.

Comment: `list1.isEmpty() || list1==null` will still throw an NPE.

Comment: @Dukeling, indeed. You need to reverse the expressions

Comment: @Bathsheba I am still a beginner,have not competed 1 month

Comment: @javaBeginner, aren't we all?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your list1-var is not initialized. You should check this way:

```
if(list1 == null || list1.isEmpty())
```